# Why does the result always stay the same?

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to programming in general and I tried making this function
but every time I call it the same result pops up

```
 def random():
     if np.random.rand() > 30:
         print("Big number")
     elif np.random.rand() < 30:
         print("Small number")
```

No error messages its just that np.random.rand() stays a single variable and doesn't change

Comment: `np.random.rand()` is a number between 0 and 1; it can never be greater than 30.

Comment: @Selcuk is correct. Also, you are generating a new random number in each if statement, you don't need the second condition you can just use `else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [randint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) to check integer values less or greater than 30

```
import numpy as np
def random():
     rand_num = np.random.randint(50) 
     print(rand_num)
     if rand_num > 30:
         print("Big number")
     elif rand_num < 30:
         print("Small number")
random()
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here is that np.random.rand() returns a value between 0-1 (see the numpy docs). If you want to generate a random number between 0-100 either multiply your random value by 100 or use np.random.randint(LOW, HIGH).

You should also know that you shouldn't be using np.random.rand in the if statement as part of the conditional, you should store the value in a variable and use that variable in the conditionals.

```
    def random():
     val=np.random.rand() * 100
     if val > 30:
         print("Big number")
     else:
         print("Small number")
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that 30 is the middle of the range you want.
Better use [`random.randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange)

```
import random


def r():
    """Choose a random item from range(start, stop[, step]).

    This fixes the problem with randint() which includes the
    endpoint; in Python this is usually not what you want.

    """
    if random.randrange(0, 60) > 30:
        print("Big number")
    else:
        print("Small number")


def main():
    for i in range(10):
        r()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```